# Why is it that sometimes showing hiding forms misfires?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

My form1 is the mainform. I use it for login purposes and after I dont need it 
I hide it. If the login is successful, on button click,form3 is called.

```
procedure TForm1.AdvGlowButton1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
ABSQuery4.Active:=false;
ABSQuery4.SQL.Clear;
ABSQuery4.SQL.Add('select .....bla,bla,bla....');
ABSQuery4.Open;
if ABSQuery4.FieldByName('passsword').AsString<>''
then  begin
Form3.Show;
Form1.Hide;
end else begin
cxTextedit1.Text := '';
showmessage('wrong password');
end;
end;
```

Now I am noticing that sometimes the event produces strange results.
Form3 is shown but Form1 remains visible also. For showing the main form
from form3 I use :

```
procedure TForm3.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
Form1.Show;
end
```

Since I need the application icon for Form3, I have there :

```
procedure TForm3.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams) ;
begin
  inherited;
  Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_APPWINDOW;
  Params.WndParent := 0;
end;
```

Can you tell me am I messing anything up or is there a better way to 
make the forms behave properly?

Comment: Aside: no point in making a form both unowned **and** adding WS_EX_APPWINDOW. Doing one is enough.

Comment: So I should remove: Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_APPWINDOW; ??

Comment: You won't need that at all if you follow the advice in my answer.

Comment: I will need to rewrite everything but first I will try with just 2 forms to see how it works. The problem is that I need to bring up this LoginForm from the mainForm too... Its an login/logout system.

Comment: That's no problem. You can create and show a form any time you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a better way to do this. For a start, you should give your forms meaningful names!

Your real problem is that your main form is being hidden because you are using it as your login form. You make life needlessly difficult and complicated by doing that.

So the main piece of advice is that you should make you real main form be the Delphi main form. The Delphi main form is the first form created using `Application.CreateForm`. I suggest that you call `Application.CreateForm` exactly once, to create the main form.

This may leave you wondering how to create other forms. Well, you just create them using the standard constructor, just like any other object.

So your .dpr file code might look like this:

```
Application.Initialize;
LoginForm := TLoginForm.Create(nil);
try
  if LoginForm.ShowModal <> mrOK then
    exit;
finally
  LoginForm.Free;
end;
Application.CreateForm(TMainForm, MainForm);
Application.Run;
```

Once you make this change you will find that you don't need to take steps to force the main form onto the taskbar.

Comment: Why am I getting [dcc32 Error] Project1.dpr(14): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'mrOK'

Comment: Because you have not used the unit which declares `mrOK`. It is declared in `System.UITypes`.

Comment: i am wondering why is it that my mainform remains visible if I told it to hide ?

Comment: Your app is a little bit messy, to be honest. And the code you have posted is incomplete, yet still contains code not relevant to the issue at hand. For example the SQL code. I answered *is there a better way to make the forms behave properly?" I would not like to pick apart your program without a good SSCCE.